# Regex to match specific URL

Tags: php, regex, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, preg-match

Can someone please help im trying to do a rewrite rule with regex matching a  specific URL format.

I need something that says if the URL is

```
www.site.ag/whatever
```

to redirect to `/index` page.

Comment: here's a good place to start.  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html

Comment: "What have you tried?" - what code/work have you done to attempt to do this yourself? This site will try better to help if you show some effort. We are here to assist.

Comment: Try [`parse_url()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Comment: Well im a php guy but havent worked too much with regex honestly i only know the basics. Tried a few combinations but i dont think i was doing it right

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if that is what do you need, but this will redirect everything to index.php with exception of urls to actual existing files or directories.

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

Comment: this actually ended up being a server specific configuration that i needed to put through instead of a rewrite code.